# Makefile store powershell output in a variable for futher use

Tags: makefile, eval, gnu-make

System: Win10 with MinGW make

I am trying to store PowerShell output in a variable inside of the recipe, and unfortunately I've exhausted all options.

Variable that stores powershell command:

```
# Get newest package in the directory
LST_PKG := powershell "gci -Path . -File *.nipkg -Recurse -Name | sort creationtime | Select -First 1"
```

The output is `builds\packages\srl-lut_1.2.0.32_windows_all.nipkg`

The actual recipe that's not working (PKG_REL_PATH end up empty):

```
.PHONY: publish

publish: clean build package
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    @echo "Publishing a DEBUG package..."
    
#1. Copy package to feed repo
    $(eval PKG_REL_PATH = $(LST_PKG))
    cp $(ROOT_DIR)$(PKG_REL_PATH) $(TEST_FEED_REPO)
    
#2. Publish the package
    
else
    @echo "Publishing a RELEASE package..." 
endif
```

Partial output indicative of the issue:

```
"Publishing a DEBUG package..."
cp C:\Users\Public\Projects\SRL\lut\src\powershell "gci -Path . -File *.nipkg -Recurse -Name | sort creationtime | Select -First 1" \\raven\#Raven\SRLFeeds\SRL\Repo
'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [makefile:78: publish] Error 1
```

It looks like LST_PKG does not expans and evaluate and just assigned as string to PKG_REL_PATH:
cp C:\Users\Public\Projects\SRL\lut\src***powershell "gci -Path . -File *.nipkg -Recurse -Name | sort creationtime | Select -First 1"*** \raven\#Raven\SRLFeeds\SRL\Repo

Answer (score 0):

1. Using make functions in recipes, like `eval`, is usually wrong.
2. Your `eval` simply creates a copy of make variable `LST_PKG` named `PKG_REL_PATH`, it does not execute the `powershell` command.
3. The error message you get seems to say that there is no `cp` command in the shell used by make to execute the recipes. This is quite strange. Do you know what shell make uses?

Assuming you find a way to solve the 3rd issue, you could simply try:

```
# Get newest package in the directory
LST_PKG := powershell "gci -Path . -File *.nipkg -Recurse -Name | sort creationtime | Select -First 1"
PKG_REL_PATH := $(shell $(LST_PKG))
```

The `shell` make function will pass the `powershell` command to the shell. The shell will execute it and the output will be assigned to the `PKG_REL_PATH` make variable. This will happen when make parses the Makefile. If you absolutely want this command to be executed at the same time as the `publish` recipe, what you need is more likely a shell variable:

```
publish: clean build package
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    @echo "Publishing a DEBUG package..."
    PKG_REL_PATH=$$($(LST_PKG)); \
    cp $(ROOT_DIR)"$$PKG_REL_PATH" $(TEST_FEED_REPO)    
else
    @echo "Publishing a RELEASE package..." 
endif
```

Note the `$$` to escape the first expansion by make and pass `$(powershell ...)` or `$PKG_REL_PATH` to the shell. Without this the first expansion by make would eat the `$` and what would be passed to the shell would not be what you want.

Note also the chaining of the shell commands with a semi-colon and the `\` line continuation. They are absolutely needed to guarantee that the two commands are executed in the same shell. By default recipe lines are executed in different shell invocations (unless you use the GNU make `.ONESHELL` feature) and shell variables defined on one line are undefined in the next. So without the chaining and the line continuation the `PKG_REL_PATH` shell variable would not be defined in the `cp...` line.

Comment: Thank you for your time detailing the answer, @Renaud Pacalet. You explanations make a lot of sense and illuminate some gaps in understanding that I have. The second variant is appropriate to my application: I must use this command as part of `publish` recipe since physical package is not available until that point of time (so locating it would fail). I modified my makefile to use your suggestion and unfortunately still getting similar errors in expansion/running the command:

Comment: ```PS C:\Users\lut\src> make publish                                                                                                                                                                     "Publishing a DEBUG package..."
PKG_REL_PATH=$(powershell "gci -Path . -File *.nipkg -Recurse -Name | sort creationtime | Select -First 1"); \  
    cp C:\Users\Public\Projects\SRL\lut\src\"$PKG_REL_PATH" \\raven#Raven\SRLFeeds\SRL\Repo  
'PKG_REL_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [makefile:77: publish] Error 1```

Comment: As I explained, you must first solve the 3rd issue: apparently the shell that executes the recipes is not sh or bash. Try to print what it is by putting `$(info the shell is $(SHELL))` anywhere on a separate line in your Makefile. Run make and see what happens.

Comment: `the shell is sh.exe`

Comment: OK, this is the name of the executable. If you have a command line interface can you try `sh.exe --version`?

Comment: I removed `cp` to bypass the offender to see if make would expand PKG_REL_PATH, and it still results in `C:\Users\Public\Projects\SRL\lut\src\"$PKG_REL_PATH" \\raven#Raven\SRLFeeds\SRL\Repo`

Comment: I am Windows10 running make thru MinGW using Windows PowerShell. I can't call `sh.exe` from CMD or PowerShell

Comment: Hmm. Sorry but I am not a Windows user and I am afraid I cannot help about this. On all systems I know make executes the recipes with one form or another of the bourne shell, which knows what shell variable assignments are (`PKG_REL_PATH=...`) and `cp` is defined. Try to find maybe a Windows expert who knows what this strange shell is and what utilities are available?

Comment: Thank you, Renaud. Appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. First, I define a CMD-type copy command to be used instead on cp (at the beginning of the makefile, outside of all recipes:

```
# Copy a file from targed to destination
_CP = cmd /C copy
```

The correct expansion was archived by doing the following:

IS

```
publish:
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    @echo "Publishing a DEBUG package..."
    
#1. Copy package to feed repo
    $(_CP) "$(ROOT_DIR)$(shell $(_LST_PKG))" "$(TEST_FEED_REPO)"

#2. Publish the package
else
    @echo "Publishing a RELEASE package..." 
endif
```

WAS

```
publish: clean build package
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    @echo "Publishing a DEBUG package..."
    
#1. Copy package to feed repo
    $(eval PKG_REL_PATH = $(LST_PKG))
    cp $(ROOT_DIR)$(PKG_REL_PATH) $(TEST_FEED_REPO)
    
#2. Publish the package
    
else
    @echo "Publishing a RELEASE package..." 
endif
```

In summary, I used `$(shell ...)` inline evaluation to bypass all variable assignment which was giving the issue in the first place.